# How to read a csv with a broken header in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with opening CSV file using Pandas in Jupyter and then I tried to open it in Visual studio and it's also not working. What am I missing?

Code in Jupyter:

```
path = 'data/DATA_vozila_RAW.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

I also tried adding encoding="Latin-1" to the code.

Code in Visual studio:

```
data = pd.read_csv('DATA_vozila_RAW.csv', encoding="Latin-1", delimiter=",")
print(data)
```

Data:
[image]

Error:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(path)

```
File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:950, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    936     dialect,
    937     delimiter,
   (...)
    946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    947 )
    948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:611, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    608     return parser
    610 with parser:
--> 611     return parser.read(nrows)

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1778, in TextFileReader.read(self, nrows)
   1771 nrows = validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
   1772 try:
   1773     # error: "ParserBase" has no attribute "read"
   1774     (
   1775         index,
   1776         columns,
   1777         col_dict,
-> 1778     ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
   1779         nrows
   1780     )
   1781 except Exception:
   1782     self.close()

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:230, in CParserWrapper.read(self, nrows)
    228 try:
    229     if self.low_memory:
--> 230         chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
    231         # destructive to chunks
    232         data = _concatenate_chunks(chunks)

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:808, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory()

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:866, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:852, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

File ~\Desktop\analitika_podatkov\work_dir\python-analitika-public\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:1973, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

Comment: How does the data in the file look like? Do you use the correct seperator `sep`? [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv) is a powerful but complex function with many options to set. If you don't get it work, please copy the head of your file so we can try to reproduce your error message.

Comment: I added a picture of Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header of your csv file seems to be broken/split in *two separate lines*.

If so, you can start by making a list of the header names and pass it to `names` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
with open("DATA_vozila_RAW.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    headers = " ".join([line.strip() for line in csv_file.readlines()[:2]]).split(";")
    
data = pd.read_csv("DATA_vozila_RAW.csv", encoding="Latin-1", delimiter=";",
                   skiprows=2, header=None, names=headers).iloc[:, 2:]
```

Output (*in Jupyter*) :

[image]